# ffmpeg: "Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

Using ffmpeg, I get the warning

```
Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss
```

In my case, speed an cpu consuption matter.

I found two discussions about that. Both are quite old:

[https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-October/037501.html#:~:text=This%20can%20lead%20to%20a%20speedloss.%20%3E,(i.e.%20may%20be%20slower)](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-October/037501.html#:%7E:text=This%20can%20lead%20to%20a%20speedloss.%20%3E,(i.e.%20may%20be%20slower)).

https://superuser.com/questions/728795/new-ffmpeg-swscaler-0xa314080-warning-data-is-not-aligned-this-can-lead

Every cropping and also every rescaling process as well as the placement of the pip is a multiple of 16 in my case. Also the input (2560x1920) meets that criteria.

Here is the code:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg \
-fflags nobuffer \
-rtsp_transport tcp \
-i 'rtsp://XXX' \
-timeout 6000000 \
-r 0.5 \
-copyts \
-an \
-hls_flags delete_segments+append_list \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]split=2[a][b];\
[a]scale=768:576[c];\
[b]crop=256:272:1008:608,scale=320:240[d];\
[d]pad=w=16+iw:h=16+ih:x=16:y=16:color=#ff78a8[e];\
[c][e]overlay=0+16:0+32[f]" \
-map "[f]" \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -r 0.5 -g 0.5 -sc_threshold 0 \
-f segment \
-segment_list_flags live \
-segment_time 3 \
-segment_list_size 3 \
-segment_format mpegts \
-segment_list_type m3u8 \
-segment_list_entry_prefix /XXX/stream/ \
-segment_list /var/www/video_streaming/XXX/index_4.m3u8 \
/var/www/video_streaming/XXX/stream/s4_%d.ts
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't worry about the speed loss. The x86 architecture is not so sensitive to data alignment, and the speed loss is usually negligible. When using the FFmpeg C interface, there is more control over the data alignment, but when using FFmpeg CLI, there is no control. Any padding (or format conversion) you add for solving the alignment issue, is probably going to lower the performance. For better performance, you may try using scale with bi-linear interpolation instead of the default interpolation... What is `-g 0.5`?